# Bootstrap CDN overrides custom CSS in Django

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have tried everything mentioned on the internet but yet bootstrap CDN overrides the custom CSS file.
The HTML file:

```
{%extends 'movies/base.html'%}
{%block content%}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
 </head>


  <body>
    <div class="section">
    <h1>Recommend Me:</h1>
  <form action="recommendation" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="emotion" />
    <button type="submit" name="button">Find</button>
  </form>

  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      <video autoplay loop muted >
        <source src="{% static 'movies/intro.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="shows">
  <h2 class="mt-5">Shows you might like:</h2>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    {%for tvshow in tvshows%}
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6">

      <a href="{{ tvshow.url }}">
        <img src="{{ tvshow.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
      </a>
      <h3>{{ tvshow.title }}</h3>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
{%endblock%}
```

I tried adding the attribute `!important` in CSS but yet it didn't work.

CSS file:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.video-container video{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 570px;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.section h1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.section form{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: auto;
}

.color-overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #03a9f4;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

.shows{
  position: relative;
  height:400px;
  top: 230px;
  padding: 20px;
  width:100%;
}
```

I also gave an ID to the body tag and then changed the CSS file, for example: `#mypage .section` but still it didn't work.

If I remove the bootstrap CDN link from the header file then the custom CSS file runs like a charm. I have no idea why bootstrap CDN is overriding the custom CSS file.

the HTML file extends `base.html` so I just wanted to say that base.html has no bootstrap stuff attached to it. It has no styling sheets.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: How would it look if you move `{% load static %}` above `{%block content%}`?

Comment: @AD Bootstrap is still overriding the custom CSS file even after I did what you said :(